# Find all the invariant invariant subspaces for the regular representation of $S_3$.

Tags: permutations, representation-theory

Using a [little program](https://github.com/davidamaro/stancu) I can build the regular representation of $S_3$ (the permutation group of three elements). The textbook that I am reading only tells that the regular representation contains all the irreducible representations of $S_3$ but gives no basis (before Young technique) to decompose the representation.

So I've tried to diagonalize the representation using the vectors $(1,1,1,1,1,1)$, $(-1,4,-1,-1,-1,-1)$, $(-1,-1,4,-1,-1,-1)$, $(-1,-1,-1,4,-1,-1)$, $(-1,-1,-1,-1,4,-1)$ and $(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,4)$ I am able to write the representation using this basis and I get the desired block diagonal form of the matrices:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1.0 & 0.0&  0.0&  0.0&  0.0&  0.0\\
 0.0 & 1.0&  0.0&  0.0&  0.0&  0.0\\
 0.0 & 0.0&  1.0&  0.0&  0.0&  0.0\\
 0.0 & 0.0&  0.0&  1.0&  0.0&  0.0\\
 0.0 & 0.0&  0.0&  0.0&  1.0&  0.0\\
 0.0 & 0.0&  0.0&  0.0&  0.0&  1.0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1.0  &  0.0    &       0.0  & 0.0  & 0.0  & 0.0\\
 0.0  & -1.0   &        0.0 &  0.0 &  0.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0  & -1.0   &        0.0 &  0.0 &  1.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0  & -1.0   &        0.0 &  0.0 &  0.0 &  1.0\\
 0.0  & -1.0   &        1.0 &  0.0 &  0.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0  & -1.0   &        0.0 &  1.0 &  0.0 &  0.0     
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1.0  & 0.0  &  0.0 &  0.0 &  0.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0  & 0.0  & -1.0 &  1.0 &  0.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0  & 0.0  & -1.0 &  0.0 &  0.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0  & 1.0  & -1.0 &  0.0 &  0.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0  & 0.0  & -1.0 &  0.0 &  0.0 &  1.0\\
 0.0  & 0.0  & -1.0 &  0.0 &  1.0 &  0.0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1.0 & 0.0 &  0.0  &  0.0 &  0.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0 & 0.0 &  1.0  & -1.0 &  0.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0 & 0.0 &  0.0  & -1.0 &  0.0 &  1.0\\
 0.0 & 0.0 &  0.0  & -1.0 &  1.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0 & 0.0 &  0.0  & -1.0 &  0.0 &  0.0\\
 0.0 & 1.0 &  0.0  & -1.0 &  0.0 &  0.0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1.0 &  0.0&  0.0&  0.0&   0.0&  0.0\\
 0.0 &  0.0&  0.0&  0.0&  -1.0&  1.0\\
 0.0 &  1.0&  0.0&  0.0&  -1.0&  0.0\\
 0.0 &  0.0&  0.0&  0.0&  -1.0&  0.0\\
 0.0 &  0.0&  0.0&  1.0&  -1.0&  0.0\\
 0.0 &  0.0&  1.0&  0.0&  -1.0&  0.0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1.0 &  0.0 &  0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
 0.0 &  0.0  & 0.0  &0.0  &1.0  &-1.0\\
 0.0 &  0.0  & 0.0  &1.0  &0.0  &-1.0\\
 0.0 &  0.0  & 1.0  &0.0  &0.0  &-1.0\\
 0.0 &  1.0  & 0.0  &0.0  &0.0  &-1.0\\
 0.0 &  0.0  & 0.0  &0.0  &0.0  &-1.0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Can you give me (using or not the Young tableaux technique) the basis that shows, explicitly, the block diagonal structure showing the invariant subspaces?

Comment: The simple representations of $S_3$ are easy to list: the trivial one, the sign representation, and the two-dimensional representation. Call these $V_1, V_2, V_3$. The Artin-Wedderburn theorem tells you that you can take the product of defining homomorphisms to obtain an isomorphism $\rho: \mathbb C[S_3] \to \operatorname{End}(V_1) \times \operatorname{End}(V_2) \times \operatorname{End}(V_3)$; if you have explicit descriptions of $V_1, V_2, V_3$, then this isomorphism is explicit, and you only need to figure out inverse images of a nice choice of basis on the right-hand side.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I'm not a mathematician. My textbook is for physicists. Of course, I can study this but... you know if someone did it explicitly?

Comment: I'm sure many people have done it explicitly. Just don't know where might be a good place to look.